# deleting constraints values after declaring of primary and foreign keys

Tags: sql, oracle

how  to delete one of the references out of multiple references in a constraint

```
constraint fk_id foreign key (relation_id,relation_rank)
references family (family_id,family_rank)
);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Please edit the question with important info like which database are you using, what have you tried before posting the question, what worked what not.

Comment: @MayankJain im working on oracle db i want to delete one of the referenced column in the constraint and if i write a code like this while creating a table how can i alter it in future based on requirement

Comment: @MayankJain how to delete one single reference out of multiple references in a constraint

Comment: There is not alter constraint. You can drop it and rebuild it to your new specification - that is the only option.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle it is

`Alter Table <tableName> drop constraint <constraintName>;`

and then recreate it with one fewer column

Comment: i want to delete one of the foreign key references. by dropping the constraint  all the references will be dropped

Comment: Just drop the constraint and recreate it with one fewer column. Dropping a FK constraint does not alter the data in the  tables.